# Mailings -> New mailing gives 404 Not found (NGINX)

Tags: civimail, drupal, nginx

We've nginx installed as a proxy.  While attempting to start New Mailing 
`civicrm/mailing/send?reset=1` browser tries to reach `civicrm/a/#/mailing/new` url, ending with **404 Not Found** nginx error. Nginx error log says *"httpdocs/civicrm/a/index.html" is not found*

It sounds pretty much the same as this question: ['Unknown path' error when trying to access New Mailing with version 4.6.2](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2581/unknown-path-error-when-trying-to-access-new-mailing-with-version-4-6-2) , and we've no any modules installed.

However, solution mentioned in first comment  works for us. This is it:

> After changing line 56 in file civicrm/CRM/Mailing/Controller/Send.php like below, it now works.

```
- CRM_Utils_System::redirect(CRM_Utils_System::url('civicrm/a/', NULL, TRUE, '/mailing/new'));
+ CRM_Utils_System::redirect(CRM_Utils_System::url('civicrm/a', NULL, TRUE, '/mailing/new'));
```

But the question still is: do we need to perform something at NGINX configuration ( since pure Apache setup doesn't have this issue ) or it's a bug in the core, which should be reported / fixed?

Drupal 7.40 + Civicrm 4.6.9

Comment: Unfortunately, solution proposed for  civicrm/CRM/Mailing/Controller/Send.php doesn't work, so would be nice to make it works somehow. Putting hash sign as a second argument of CRM_Utils_System::url doesn't seems to be a good idea

Answer (score 1):

You have an error with the configuration of your nginx that doesn't properly redirect to drupal /civicrm/a/ but does it for /civicrm/a.

What configuration did you choose for your drupal/nginx? 
I started with that one and whitelisted a few more urls (in extern/ folder)
https://github.com/perusio/drupal-with-nginx and it works fine

Comment: Ahh, almost forgot about it; thanks to someone who has brought it at the top of the queue here. Will have a look at perusio's config; may I ask how has you whitelisted these URLs (always have a problem selecting from various variations of nginx configs created by perusio..)